# The methods I'm using are unbound?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a calendar via Python's HTMLCalendar and Django. The functions I'm using to input data into the calendar are showing up as unbound, and therefore not working.

Here's the calendar code:

```
from www.wednesday.models import Event
import calendar
e = Event()
class EventCal(calendar.HTMLCalendar):

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day == 0:
            return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>' # Day outside month
        if day == e.dd():
            return '<td class="%s">%d</p><a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\">%s</a></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, e.link(), e.res())
        else:
            return '<td class="%s">%d</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)

class rendCal:
    c = EventCal(calendar.SUNDAY)
```

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    Restaurant = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    LinkURL = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    DateDay = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)

    def dd(self):
        return '%i' % self.DateDay

    def link(self):
        return '%s' % self.LinkURL

    def res(self):
        return '%s' % self.Restaurant
```

And lastly, my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import www.wednesday.models
from www.wednesday.cal import rendCal
import datetime as dt

def calendar(request):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    cal = rendCal.c.formatmonth(now.year, now.month)
    return render_to_response('cal.html', {'calendar': cal})
```

Everything works except for the functions from Event that are called inside the EventCal class.

Obviously I'm quite new at this.

Okay, @Marcin asked for an error, this is what I'm seeing, also I corrected the capitalization.

```
TypeError at /calendar/
unbound method dd() must be called with Event instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
cal.py in formatday, line 9
```

The environment variables in EventCal from Event are showing up blank, I'm pretty sure that's why I'd been getting the needs int not str error.  When I change e.dd() to a static number, it returns everything but e.link() and e.res().

Comment: This is a pretty good question, but can we see the error? Nothing looks obviously wrong to me, although I will note that it is customary to have fields start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Please indent the error message just like the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dd() is a method of an instance of the class.

You call it like this:

```
e = Event()
x = e.dd()
```

You can't apply dd to Event itself.

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, so I am not sure how you need to modify your code.

Comment: Well, I think we do know how he needs to modify his code: not write as if it was Java (what are those getters doing there?).

Answer (score 0):

In `formatday` you have:

```
if day == 0:
```

but also:

```
if day == Event.dd():
```

and `Event.dd()` returns a string.

So, is `day` an int or a string?

Comment: Evgeny's solution actually brought me here. It was because I couldn't apply Event to itself. However, now this is my problem. It was a string before, but I've changed its field to `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` because `DecimalField` didn't work either. Now I'm getting `TypeError at /calendar/ %d format: a number is required, not str` error even though I changed the field to an int

Comment: `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` is "A field of integers separated by commas" (according to the documentation), which suggests that it's not an int. The error message "a number is required, not str" also suggests that it's not an int, but a string consisting of integers separated by commas. What about `IntegerField`? That sounds more likely.